# `std::to_string(INFINITY)` gives seg fault with `g++ -O3`

Tags: c++, string, segmentation-fault, g++, tostring

With g++ version `gcc version 7.5.0 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~16.04)`   , when I compile this code like `g++ -O3 <file>`, and run the executable, then the app gives a [seg fault](https://godbolt.org/z/rcWcWE7Pv)

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                                                                    
#include <cmath> 
#include <string>                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                       
void test() {                                                                                                                                                                          
  std::cout << "test: " << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                  
  std::cout << "init" << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                    
  std::cout << "inf" << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                     
  std::cout << std::to_string(INFINITY) << std::endl;                                                                                                                                  
  std::cout << "init done" << std::endl;                                                                                                                                               
}                                                                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                                                                       
int main ()                                                                                                                                                                            
{                                                                                                                                                                                      
  std::cout << "test: " << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                  
  std::cout << "init" << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                    
  std::cout << "inf" << std::endl;                                                                                                                                                     
  std::cout << std::to_string(INFINITY) << std::endl;                                                                                                                                  
  std::cout << "init done" << std::endl;                                                                                                                                               
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                            
}                                                                                                                                                                                      
~
```

The seg fault call stack is below:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400f01 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, 
std::allocator<char> >, char>(int (*)(char*, unsigned long, char const*, __va_list_tag*), unsigned long, char const*, ...) [clone .constprop.20] ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000400f01 in std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<cha
r>, std::allocator<char> >, char>(int (*)(char*, unsigned long, char const*, __va_list_tag*), unsigned long, char const*, ...) [clone .constprop.20] ()
#1  0x0000000000400c63 in main ()
```

Interestingly, when I comment `test` function, then it does not happen.. Not sure if it is a case of memory corruption

Other facts

- **This does not happen if I do not use** `-O3`

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rcWcWE7Pv)

Comment: So if you comment out the function `test` (which you don't even call) the program works fine? Then that seems like a bug in the compiler. Have you tested it with other compilers, or other versions of GCC? [The compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org) might be a good place to start. It also allows you to see (and compare) the generated assembly for different compilers.

Comment: That's probably a bug. Ubuntu 16.04 and gcc 7.5 are very old and I'm surprised you can even use Ubuntu 16.04 for much these days. I thought 18.04 was a pain after EOL. I would upgrade.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes removing test removes this issue

Comment: @cryptickey Note that this is not guaranteed to work. You need to include `#include<string>` to use `std::to_string`. Some compiler might compile this without the necessary include.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Here is a [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rcWcWE7Pv) where we get segmentation fault.

Comment: Even if we include that, the issue happens

Comment: @user12002570 Yes, that's probably a bug in the very old gcc version.

Comment: @cryptickey Yeah I noticed. I've added the demo link to your question so that people can also check for themselves. Upgrading would be nice as Ted said.

Comment: @user12002570 An even smaller MRE: https://godbolt.org/z/G7G7nx1Tf - It's interesting that it doesn't crash if I change `0.f` to an `int` in the unused function.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was just going to report a bug and then I saw this old bug report [7 Regression SEGFAULT when logging std::to_string(NAN)](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86274)

Answer (score 3):

This is an old [gcc bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86274) and also noticed that SEGFAULT does not happen with `-O2`, but only `-O3`. This was [fixed/patched](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/gcc-patches/2018-07/msg00165.html) in the later versions.

[[7 Regression] SEGFAULT when logging std::to_string(NAN)](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86274)

Comment: This issue also happens with `-O4`

Comment: @cryptickey I've added it as a [comment](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86274#c22) at the old report.